# fundamental group of quotient (singular) tori

Tags: quotient-spaces, fundamental-groups, singularity

What we know about fundamental group of quotient singular manifold?
I'm particularly interesting in the case of quotient given by $X:=T/G$ where $T$ is a complex torus and $G$ is finite.

Since $\pi_1$ is a topological objet how the singular of $X$ can affect it? I mean $X$ is endowed with the quotient topology so the loop are defined in the usual way?

But then if I take any resolution $\widetilde{X}$ how $\pi_1(\widetilde{X})$ is related with $\pi_1(X)$? Does this relation depend of the type of singularities (canonical, terminal..)? But I wanna to know it not only in the case of isolated singularities but in the general case.. so maybe it depends only on the codimension of the locus of points with non trivial stabilizer (?)

I know that it can be related with the notion of orbifold, but I don't have too much background on it so if it is necessarily can anyone suggest me a good reference on it?

Thanks!

Comment: See M. Armstrong, The fundamental group of the orbit space of a discontinuous group. Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. 64 (1968) 299–301.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a look!

Comment: With regards to resolutions you may be interested to know that $\pi_1$ is a birational invariant of complex algebraic varieties.

Comment: Oh thanks! This is exactly what i want to know.. do you know any reference? Because i believe that the idea is that since topologically doing a blow up means to introduce a certain $\mathbb{P}^r$-bundle (where $r$ is the codimension of the submanifold along which I blow up my manifold) and the fundamental group of $\mathbb{P}^r$ is trivial then $\pi_1$ is a birational invariant .. but of course this is not a rigourous proof so I prefer to have a good reference.

Comment: okey maybe I found a reference, basically it follows from the fact that blowing up a sub manifold means doing a connected sum with some projective bundle

Comment: The reference is  (SGA I, X, 3.4). Sorry I missed one hypothesis, the fundamental group is an invariant of proper regular vareities. Also the fundamental group may have little to do with $\pi_1(X)$, the branched covering of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ by an elliptic curve may be seen as the quotient of an algebraic $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action with 4 fixed points. However fixed point free actions will give the covering of $T$ by itself. Its hard to say much without knowing something more about the action of  $G$.